# How to minimize the speed effect of loading jQuery with a star-rated voting

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, pagespeed, lighthouse

Recently, I implemented in 10,000+ of my webpages a voting system based on star-rating and jQuery.

It works ok, it's cool, but Google started to warn me about a lack of speed ("FID issue: longer than 300ms (mobile)").

I've been analyzing the "Max Potential First Input Delay" through the audits of Chrome+Lighthouse, but I'm not able to slash this value below 300 ms. Initially, I had the code within the 'body' section.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, I've placed it before in the 'head' section and with 'async'

```
<script async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but the value of "Max Potential First Input Delay" is not reduced. Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you,

Comment: Then it's probably not jQuery causing the issue. The next likely candidate is the voting system.